# How to configure JBoss AS4 and Wildfly 10 to communicate via JMX to each other? (JGroups)

Tags: jboss, wildfly, jgroups

I have 2 clusters of JBoss servers - one cluster of JBoss 4.2.1 and one cluster of Wildfly 10.

I'd like to configure the two clusters to be able to exchange JMX notifications between each other.

While Wildfly 10 uses JGroups with "RELAY2" support, JBoss 4.2.1 uses JGroups 2.4.1, which does not support "RELAY2".

Is there any way to configure the two different clusters to be able to exchange JMX notifications with each other?  How can I configure my Wildfly 10 nodes to join my JB4 cluster?

Answer (score 0):

As per RedHat support, there is unfortunately no way to have the two clusters talk to each other as they are using different clustering techniques, even if both rely on JGroups for the communication mechanism.